# Possible to enlarge an array with each iteration , if a condition is met?

Tags: c, malloc

I have this struct

```
typedef struct
{
    int numberPipes;              // |
    int numberAmpersands;         // &
    int existsBiggerThan;         // >
    int existsLessThan;           // <
    int existsDoubleLargerThan;   // >>

} lineData;
```

and I run in my loop on a `char` array (char*), in order to find all indexes of `'&'` and `'|'` .

I don't know how much `'&'` and `'|'` I'm going to find . Is it possible to start with two arrays (using `malloc`) 
of size 1 and enlarge them after each iteration , only if I find another occurrence of one of them  ?

Comment: You cannot enlarge an array, an array has a fixed size. You can enlarge a dyn. allocated memory-block.

Comment: @user411313: Of course you're right. I meant to a dynamic allocated (char * array) array .

Comment: Better off with a linked list, resizing an array is a very expensive operation. I'd rather initialise it to the number of chars in the line than do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by calling [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/).

For performance reasons, it might be better to call it not for each new element, but once in X elements, so you reduce the number of calls to `malloc` / `realloc`.